Should I say, "Canada consumed over 50 million kilograms of rice in 2021"?

Canada consumed over 50 million kilograms of rice in 2021.

I wonder if I can use a country's name to refer to all the people living there. Thank you!

You can. The country name stands for all of the people in it. Britain drank the equivalent of 1.12 billion gin and tonics in 2016, the Wine and Spirit Trade Association said. and France eats more pizza than any other country after Italy

I would personally change the sentence this way:
"Canadians consumed over 50000 tons of rice in 2021."
Preferably using tons when talking huge numbers as well, I generally recommend using kilos when you want to display an accurate amount.

I'd argue that in this instance kilos would be a more intuitive quantity, because (at least in Europe) rice often comes in 1kg bags. When I read the original sentence in the question, I'm picturing 50 million bags of rice, but I have no intuitive handle on how big a ton of rice is.

The calculation is not difficult as 1000 kgs= 1 ton. 50 million less three zeroes (divided by 1000); is 50,000 tons

@JamesMathai - in the UK, I don't know about elsewhere, we call one thousand kilogrammes a 'tonne' or a 'metric tonne', and, I agree, it is trivially easy to imagine that a tonne is a thousand kilos. A 'ton' with no qualification in Britain is customarily 2,240 pounds, and in the US, I believe, 2,000 pounds.

@alexhroom — in Europe, rice comes in 1kg bags?  Hahaha.  In Asia, rice comes in 20kg bags...

@MichaelHarvey.  Definitely. There are “metric tons” (1000 kg, 2204.62 lbs), “short tons” (2000 lbs), and “long tons” (2200 lbs).  Without context, any American would assume a ton is a short ton.  The reference to Canada opens, but does not answer, the question of it being a metric ton.

@MichaelHarvey Before I too got confused because in cricket - hit a ton means century= 100 runs.

@JamesMathai - yes, informally 'ton' can mean 'one hundred' . Since at least the 1950s, if not before, UK motorcyclists (mainly, car drivers also) have informally called going at 100 imperial miles per hour 'doing the ton'.
